# How to set PEC flag to SM bus in device tree?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, i2c

I have a I2C/SMBus device that requires [PEC](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/i2c/smbus-protocol) and I'm writing a kernelspace driver for it.

On Linux 2.6.37 I use [i2c_board_info](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/i2c.h#L298) to instantiate the client and set the flag there, but now the driver is being ported to 3.14 and I could not find the device tree binding for the PEC flag.

Actually I don't think there is such a binding because [the I2C core is not getting any property from device tree other than `reg` and `wakeup-source`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core.c).

So shall I just do `i2c_client->flags |= I2C_CLIENT_PEC` in my device driver?

Comment: `ioctl(file, I2C_PEC, long select)
  Selects SMBus PEC (packet error checking) generation and verification
  if select not equals 0, disables if select equals 0. Default 0.
  Used only for SMBus transactions.  This request only has an effect if the
  the adapter has I2C_FUNC_SMBUS_PEC; it is still safe if not, it just
  doesn't have any effect.` From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface

Comment: @AndyShevchenko  but at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-dev.c#L438 it seems that it's userspace I2C api and won't affect kernel space i2c devices.

Comment: And why do you need it exactly at kernel level?

Comment: @AndyShevchenko I'm writing a driver for lc709203f battery fuel gauge (http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/LC709203F-D.PDF),  and using this driver as an example (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/power/ds2782_battery.c). LC709203 requires PEC. All writes to it without PEC are ignored.

Comment: It wasn't in the original question. Taking it into consideration the below answer seems more or less correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current mainline kernel(4.5) code, at least three i2c client drivers enable I2C_CLIENT_PEC flag in the driver ([ipmi_ssif](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/ipmi/ipmi_ssif.c#L1629), [lm90](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hwmon/lm90.c#L1177) and [pmbus_core](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hwmon/pmbus/pmbus_core.c#L1757)), and one of them ([lm90](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hwmon/lm90.c#L1177)) exposes it to sysfs.

I believe it's safe to do `i2c_client->flags |= I2C_CLIENT_PEC` in the client driver.

Comment: I do not agree. If something can be done in userspace, what prevents to do it there?